# Writing a function template that is specialised for a class and its subclasses

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am trying to write a function template. One version should be used for all types that don't satisfy the criteria for the other version; the other version should be used when the argument is a base class of a given class, or that class itself.

I have tried doing an overload for `Base&`, but when classes are derived from `Base`, they use the general one, not the specific one.

I also have tried this SFINAE approach:

```
struct Base { };

struct Derived : public Base { };

struct Unrelated { };

template<typename T>
void f(const T& a, bool b = true) {
    cout << "not special" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void f(const Base& t, bool b = is_base_of<Base, T>::value) {
    cout << "special" << endl;
}

Base b;
Derived d;
Unrelated u;

f(b); f(d); f(u);
```

But all of them print "not special". I am not good at SFINAE and I am probably just doing it wrong. How can I write a function like this?

Comment: Are you looking for a C++03 or C++11 solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, none of these will ever call the "special" `f` overload because `T` cannot be deduced from the function arguments.  Its first parameter needs to be of type `T`:

```
void f(const T& t, bool b = is_base_of<Base, T>::value)
```

Once that is done, note that the "special" overload doesn't really use SFINAE to affect overload resolution:  `is_base_of<T, U>::value` always has a value:  it's either `true` or `false`.  To affect overload resolution, you need to use `enable_if`, which conditionally defines a type based on a boolean value.

Also, both overloads need to use SFINAE:  the "special" overload must be enabled if `T` is derived from the base (or is the base type), and the "not special" overload must be enabled only if `T` is not derived from the base, otherwise there will be overload resolution ambiguities.

The two overloads should be declared and defined as:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T const& a, typename enable_if<!is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type* = 0)
{
    cout << "not special" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void f(T const& t, typename enable_if<is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type* = 0)
{
    cout << "special" << endl;
}
```

Finally, note that there is no specialization here.  These two functions named `f` are *overloads*.

Comment: Thanks, works nicely. I wish there were a way to do it without polluting the argument list though, but I doubt that is possible without using a `class` wrapper or something which I don't want to do.

Comment: You can "pollute" the return type, if you prefer (just move the `typename enable_if` etc. to be the return type).  Either way works equally well.  Neither is particularly readable :-)

Comment: Unfortunately the return value is used though, so can't do that.

Comment: `typename enable_if<is_base_of<Base, T>::value, int>::type f()` will give `f()` a return type of `int` if `T` is derived from or is `Base`.  The second template argument of `enable_if` is optional and defaults to `void`, but you can specify any type.

Comment: Wha, how stupid of me. I am making many stupid mistakes today.

Comment: Thanks, that works even better. Now I have written my first template nonsense with your help; the return type of my functions are now `typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value, T>::type` :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple C++03 approach:

```
namespace detail // implementation details, users never invoke these directly
{
    template<bool B>
    struct f_impl
    {
        template<typename T>
        static void f(T const& t) { std::cout << "not special\n"; }
    };

    template<>
    struct f_impl<true>
    {
        static void f(Base const& t) { std::cout << "special\n"; }
    };
}

template<typename T>
void f(T const& t)
{
    detail::f_impl<is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::f(t);
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/LD2Ex).

Comment: The non-SFINAE overloading does not work because "not special" is an exact match for `Derived`, but "special" requires a derived-to-base conversion, so "not special" is selected during overload resolution.

Comment: Your second approach does not work, since the templated overload is more suitable for class `Derived` than the `Base` argument one.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use something that doesn't require people to go through a class to get to the function. +1 though since it does work.

Comment: @Seth : To be clear, `f_impl<>` is an implementation detail; users would only ever call the globally-scoped `f` function template. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @ildjarn ohhh I see, that was stupid of me. Let me reconsider which one is better for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with overloading would be like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base { };

struct Derived : public Base { };

struct Unrelated { };

void f(...) {
    cout << "not special" << endl;
}

void f(const Base& t) {
    cout << "special" << endl;
}

int main(){ 
    Base b;
    Derived d;
    Unrelated u;

    f(b); 
    f(d);
    f(u);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
special
special
not special
```

An overload taking a variable argument list will take any type of argument, but is always considered less suitable than any other overload that works at all.

Comment: That's a nice way, except I do need to access the arguments non-variadically.