# Template specialization that also works for derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am trying to find out how to make a template specialization of a class member function that not only works for the template specialization class A, but all derived classes from class A.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401676/writing-a-function-template-that-is-specialised-for-a-class-and-its-subclasses), but the solution uses overloads not specilizations, so I don't see how I can adapt the answer to my problem (As I dont want to touch the function signature).

My situation is, that I have a complex class, I dont want to touch

```
template< class T >
class Complex :
    public MoreComplex
{
    public:
        //... more stuff here...
        virtual bool Start();
};

template< class T >
bool Complex< T>::Start()
{
    //do some stuff
    return true;
}
```

In the framework I am using here, this class is used by doing template specializations of the member function.
For example, when having a class A:

```
template< >
inline bool Complex<A>::Start()
{
    //do special stuff only for class A
    return true;
}
```

So far, so simple. Now I want all classes which are derived from class A to use the same implementation of the Start function. How can this be done?
After doing some searches I found the concept of SFINAE and tried the following:

```
template< class T >
inline bool Complex< typename std::conditional<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, A, void>::type >::Start()
{
    //do some a class stuff
    return true;
}
```

This does not work (not even build). I can provide you with more details, but I guess the answer may be simple and my knowledge of templates and SFINAE is way to low.

Comment: Edited the question and explained why the solution from the "duplicated question" can not be applied to my problem. (Or at least, I don't understand how)